# SharePoint Online List - Add Created and Created By columns to DispForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

Apologies if this is straightfoward, but how can I add the Created and Created By columns to the DispForm.aspx in a SharePoint Online list?

Comment: Use SharePoint designer to update the display form template by adding fields you want. You just need to drag & drop fields from SharePoint List controls & It will display information in it.

Answer (score 2):

By default in the DispForm.aspx, it will display when the item was created and who created the item as shown below.

[image]

I suppose that you means the modern display item panel. The DispForm.aspx is the classic page.

The example modern view:

[image]

To display Created and Created By on it, you can customize it using PowerApps.

[Information about modern list](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2016/07/25/modern-sharepoint-lists-are-here-including-integration-with-microsoft-flow-and-powerapps/)

[How to customize forms using PowerApps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)